# Using Linux as a Virtualbox guest on a Macbook Pro. Trying to paste into Vim, which is open in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, mac, virtualbox, vim, gnome-terminal

I am using XCFE Arch Linux as a Virtualbox guest on a Macbook Pro. Trying to paste into Vim, which is open in gnome-terminal. How can I do that? The usual suspects ("+P, Middle mouse click, etc) are not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift Control V worked. Who knew?

Comment: That's the usual shortcut for pasting into gnome-terminal (Shift+Insert should also work).

Comment: I can't find Insert on the Mac keyboard.